# Why click event works after two clicks VANILLA

Tags: javascript, event-handling, click, dom-events, event-listener

I am trying to trigger a function through a event listener with only one click.
But it occurs after two click (in the first time) if I don't do <kbd>F5</kbd> its trigger after one click.

Code:

HTML

```
    <div class="main-header-navbar">
   ....
        <span class="main-header-navbar-right-icons">
            <i class="fas fa-search header-icon"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-plus header-icon"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
```

JS

```
const ADD_FORM_BUTTON = document.querySelector(".fa-plus");
ADD_FORM_BUTTON.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (ADD_FORM.style.display === "none") {
        ADD_FORM.style.display = "flex";
    } else ADD_FORM.style.display = "none";
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your fa-plus element has no inline display setting.  It's null.  So the first time will go to the else statement.  Or whatever your `ADD_FORM` is.  Your snippet has no inline styles set.

Comment: Please show us how `ADD_FORM` is defined.

Comment: Is it a good practice to style inline?
this is a function? maybe is there a better implementation ?
    if (ADD_FORM.style.display === "none") {
        ADD_FORM.style.display = "flex";
    } else ADD_FORM.style.display = "none";

Comment: It use or not use inline styles is really a personal preference.  Some people will say they are ok.  Some would tell you to use a `hide` class (or something) that applies the display none to the elements.

Comment: can you explain me why it happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add `style="display: none;"` to your `ADD_FORM` so that it's initially hidden, then when you click on the `fa-plus` it will display it. See the snippet below:

```js
const ADD_FORM_BUTTON = document.querySelector(".fa-plus");
const ADD_FORM = document.getElementById("form");

ADD_FORM_BUTTON.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (ADD_FORM.style.display === "none") {
    ADD_FORM.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    ADD_FORM.style.display = "none"
  };
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="main-header-navbar">
  <span class="main-header-navbar-right-icons">
    <i class="fas fa-search header-icon"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-plus header-icon"></i>
  </span>
  <div id="form" style="display: none;">ADD_FORM</div>
</div>
```